# Powershell: Get-ChildItem - piping to Rename-Item and Copy-Item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that gathers a list of server names, then iterates through each server name and grabs the second to the newest folder in a directory, renames it, and copies it to another server.  I am running into trouble with getting this to work all in one command, and I am not sure what is the best way to split it up and have it work properly.  I get errors when trying different things, the main one is "rename-item: cannot evaluate parameter "NewName" because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input".  Here is the code snippet that causes this error:

```
$serverNames = Get-Content -Path "C:\servers.txt"

foreach ($serverName in $ServerNames) {

$reportServer = "a56741035"  

Get-ChildItem "\\$($serverName)\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {  $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | Rename-Item -NewName { "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name } | Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "\\$($reportServer)\c$\temp\mpos\logs" }
```

Another is "cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null".  Here is the code that causes this error:

```
$serverNames = Get-Content -Path "C:\servers.txt"

foreach ($serverName in $ServerNames) {

$reportServer = "a56741035"  

Get-ChildItem "\\$($serverName)\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {  $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -NewName { "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name } | Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "\\$($reportServer)\c$\temp\mpos\logs" } }
```

I feel like I am very close, and just don't see something.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you so much.  Have a great day.

EDITED TO INCLUDE NEWEST CODE:

```
 Get-ChildItem "\\$($serverName)\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {  $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name ) ; Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "\\$($reportServer)\c$\temp\mpos\logs" }
```

CODE FOR NEWEST COMMENTS:

```
Get-Child-Item "\\$serverName\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( "$serverName" + "" + $.Name ) ; Copy-Item ( "$serverName" + "" + $.Name ) -Destination "\\$reportServer\c$\temp\mpos\logs" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this turned out to be more difficult than I thought it would be, the trick being that Rename-Item seems to basically consume the pipelined object without giving you a chance to use that object in the subsequent name(using a scriptblock is also not really ideal, much easier to use a simple concatted string) so you need to change the `Rename-Item` portion of your loop slightly to

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name)
```

As far as the syntax changes prageeth suggests you can make them but they are unneeded and imo increase ambiguity(Get-Childitem does not require an escape character to access an admin share and there is nothing wrong with using $($) syntax even when not accessing a property).

**EDIT**

Ok after working in the comments for a bit here is an updated version of the full GCI pipeline.  I tested it successfully in my environment so fingers crossed it works for you.  Please let me know if any part of it doesn't make sense.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$serverName\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name ) -PassThru | Copy-Item  -Destination "\\$reportServer\c$\temp\mpos\logs" }
```

Comment: I think this is very close to nailing it!!!  The only part it does not accomplish is the file copy.  It does not error out...it just does not copy the file.  :)  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: oh wow yea didn't see how the pipeline was set up there, the problem there is that `rename-item` isn't passing the object through to `Copy-Item`, you can overcome 2 ways, either add a `-PassThru` switch to your `Rename-Item` or just change your `|` to a `;`, which will then treat the copy as a second command to execute in the foreach rather than a pipeline element

Comment: GETTING SO CLOSE!!!  Now it appears that it is renaming the file, but then trying to copy the file before it was renamed?  (cannot find path xxxxx because it does not exist) - and when I look at the folder, it has been renamed properly but the error is actually calling out the folder before it was renamed...does that make sense?

Comment: I included my newest code at the top, just for reference and to make sure I made the edits appropriately.  :)

Comment: It's because Copy-Item $_.FullName still has the old name from the pipeline ! Try with the new name

Comment: That's a Good catch mike, I missed the Copy part!

Comment: sorry, that was my fault, didn't think it through completely, Prageeth is correct that you can modify the name in the `Copy-Item` to work, or you can use the `PassThru` param on `Rename-Item` like below 


    `Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name ) -PassThru | Copy-Item $_ -Destination "\\$($reportServer)\c$\temp\mpos\logs"`

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan - thank you, I am unsure of what you mean by "try it with the new name"?  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio - thank you so much, when I try with the -PassThru switch, I get a new error:  "Copy-Item: the input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input".  Do you know why this is?

Comment: when you change to -passthru you also need to change `$_.fullname` to `$_` in the `Copy-Item`.  Alternatively, you could leave the `;` in place and not use the passthru and change `$_.Fullname` to `("$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name)`(which is what @Prageeth is suggesting)

Comment: @MikeGaruccio - thank you I really do appreciate your help.  I did change $_.fullname to $_ in the copy-item.  I tried the second method, with changing to ("$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name) and not using passthru...now it seems to be looking on the local machine for the file to copy, instead of the server ($serverName).  I get the error that "copy-item cannot find path 'D:\Tools\etc. etc." which is where I am running the command from.  It should be copying the file on the server ($serverName) to the local machine...I am sorry to be a pain.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio hello, I am still having the same issue described in my above comment.  Do you know how I can resolve this?  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @LilithGodess, sorry I tend to drop off of SO over the weekends, is your answer still reflective of your current code?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio here is the latest snippet of code, just for easier reference:

Comment: Get-Child-Item "\\$serverName\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name ) ; Copy-Item ( "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name ) -Destination "\\$reportServer\c$\temp\mpos\logs" }

Comment: I drop off on weekends as well - no need to be sorry, I appreciate your help and just wanted to reach back out.  Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: I added the code in my OP, since I could not figure out formatting in the comments.  Just in case that is easier to see.  :)

Comment: not sure if it's a copy error or if your code is really missing the underscores but make sure the `_` is included when calling `$_.name`, otherwise things look fine to me.  lmk if it fails after adding the `_` (or if it was already there and just got lost in formatting for SO)

Comment: @MikeGaruccio - ahhh, it was simply removed during SO formatting.  The _ is included in my $_.Name

Comment: Ok I think were losing a bit of my syntax suggestions going through the comments like this, I've updated my answer with a full working pipeline.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio - sorry for the delay, had to do some updates on my laptop yesterday and they ran long.  That last one did the trick!!!  Thank you so much for your help with the logic (and finally syntax) on this one...I really appreciate it, and it does all make sense.  Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

In situation like this is always best to analyse the command output first...

```
# Rename doesn't output anything by default
Rename-Item ToBeRenamed.txt Renamed.txt

# For most commands with that default behaviour, you can use -PassThru to force output
Rename-Item ToBeRenamed.txt Renamed.txt -PassThru

# Once we have something in the pipeline, we can pipe result to Copy-Item
Rename-Item ToBeRenamed.txt Renamed.txt -PassThru | Copy-Item -Destination C:\temp
ls C:\temp\Renamed.txt
```

I would recommend avoiding ForEach-Object here - it's not really needed. You just need to control output from commands, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As user mike mentioned, it appears that admin shares doesn't need $ to be escaped with. The real problem is rename-Item cmdlet missing the -Path parameter. Thanks for bringing that up Mike!

However I still recommend removing the extra $ over $($serverName) to reduce ambiguity.

Try this!

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$serverName\d$\mposlogs\device" | where {  $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 | Select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName { "$serverName" + "_" + $_.Name } | Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination "\\$reportServer\c$\temp\mpos\logs" } }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I made the suggested edits and reran my code and it still gives me the same error, "Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input.  A script block cannot be evaluated without input."

Comment: yea `-Path` is needed but you also can't use a scriptblock to build the name without doing some weird dot-sourcing that's just not needed.  and personally I think `$($servername)` is less ambiguous than `$servername` but that's not really relevant in this context.